# Tree comments Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Trying to implement a tree-like comments on the site via a gem - **acts-as-commentable-with-threading**.

Comments are excellent and are displayed on the site when I visit a site under the user (implemented via the gem **devise**).

But when trying to view pages anonymously, naturally, I receive an error that id is not may be due to the elements onto a blank.

This is my controller **recipes_controller.rb**:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_chef!, except: [:index, :show]
    def show
        @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
        @comments = @recipe.comment_threads.order('created_at desc')
        @user_who_commented = current_chef
        @new_comment = Comment.build_from(@recipe, @user_who_commented.id, "")
    end
...
```

**comments_controller.rb**:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController  
  before_action :authenticate_chef!

  def create
    commentable = commentable_type.constantize.find(commentable_id)
    @user_who_commented = current_chef
    @comment = Comment.build_from(commentable, @user_who_commented.id, body)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        make_child_comment
        format.html  { redirect_to(:back, :notice => 'Comment was successfully added.') }
      else
        format.html  { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
...
```

**recipe.rb**:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_commentable
...
```

In views (**recipes/show.html.erb**) I put this render :

```
<%= render partial: "comments/template", locals: {commentable: @recipe, new_comment: @comment} %>
```

I think that you may need in the controller to create something like a design *if ... else* for those who just browse the site, because the default at this point in the show method is set current_chef, because of what and error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the special case in view(probably comment template) for anonymous visit. Cause then `current_chef` would be nil. So where you're using it in view and controller, handle that properly.

A tip: You don't need to assign `current_chef` to any instance variable actually. It's already a helper method. You can call it directly from view.